# Recyclerview in Listview Android (Closed)

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have an listview which has recyclerview.listview has arrayadapter and recyclerview has separate adapter.I got jsonarray of listview with recyclerview data like this:-

```
  listview[no
            date
            status
            recyclerview[id
                         image
                         text
                         date]
          ]
```

In listview i got status.I want to disable item click of listview like this in adapter.

Note:PO is pojo class which has set get method.
This is listview adapter.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    PO details=(PO)this.getItem(position);
    if(details.getStatus()== 1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is,i want to click on imageview which is in recyclerview.My status is 1 of listview item but imageview click is working.I just want when i click on imageview of recyclerview in item1 of listview which has status 1 click would be disable.Any solution suggestion or query related to question please discuss with me.My recyclerview onclick is:

```
  holder.imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("no", current.getPoDesignId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I want to disable this when my status is 1 but i don't know how to get my status in this recyclerview adapter from listview adapter.
Thank you.

Comment: 44 times viewed but no comment....it has no solution ??? or you don't know...???

Comment: i done myself thnx to viewers.